# Printable Templates for Views using Print Module

Tags: views, theming

Any views related report can be printed using the [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module when enabled. This can be achieved by simply using /print/views-url. It uses the standard print.tpl.php.

I do not want the print version of views output to display the exposed filter. At the same time, I would not want to modify the default print.tpl.php.

Is there a way to use alternative print templates for views in the same line as for content types: print[--html|--mail|--pdf][--node--node-type].tpl.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue quite a while back and below is how I solved it:

1. Create another display of the same view (clone page)
2. Choose 'Remember last selection' in the Views exposed filters' settings in the original page view
3. In the cloned page view, set 'Expose form in a block' to 'Yes'
4. Use the regular 'print/view-url' wherever you want but remember that 'view-url' in this case is the path of the cloned page view.

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Supriya Rajgopal

Comment: This may help https://www.drupal.org/node/2037097